# Cannot Debug I/DEBUG(187): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an android application which needs lot of memory allocations(Lot of image buffers). I am using Android NDK for that. I am coming across a weird crashes. I hope this is not repeated post (after going through previous posts)

The app crashes with following error: I/DEBUG(187): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000004

1. I have come across segmentation error before and have solved it.
2. I am pretty sure that I am allocating and deallocating the memory properly, because I have same set up for windows which confirms that there are no memory leaks and I am not accessing any location which is not allocated. (No derefrencing, no bad pointers). No memory corruptions were found while testing on windows.
3. Im also sure that JNI calls made for allocations and deallocations are at proper place in the code. Memory are cleared only when the usage is done.
4. Backtrace shows **different API calls** each time the crash occurs, where the error is happening. I have taken logs and none of the pointers are null and they are as expected.
5. This crash occurs very **randomly**. Once in a while. 
     **a**. When i m inside the app for long time. 
     **b**. when lot of actions are performed inside the app. But it works well most of the time.

Can anyone suggest how the memory is getting corrupted in my code. what might be causing this.

Answer (score 6):

Check for places where you might be acessing a field from a struct or from an array. The reason I say this is because the faulty address is 00000004, which is 4 bytes after a NULL address. Check for every field access, specially in code that is performed a lot of times. 
Also, check for NULL returns from malloc/new, your device might be out of memory.

Since you said this problem occurs when there's a lot of actions performed or when the app is left running for a long time, I'd check for memmory leaks. Your app might be the one consuming all of the device memory. If you have custom allocators/deallocators, you might want to use a global counter, for every allocation you increase it, for every deallocation, decrease it. If the counter gets too hight, its a memmory leak.

Answer (score 2):

A random position of the crash often happens when the stack is corrupted, so you should look carefully for your local variables. For example, overwriting an array of length N with M or something like this.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. My native code has a global structure which has pointers to different buffers. I have two APIs one to allocate and one to deallocate. I am playing with these in my code all the time. I deallocate(say when i press done in UI). Anything fishy you could see in this.??

Comment: If you have corrupted memory which you allocated, usually the crash occurs where this mewmory is used. If you have global allocate and deallocate function you can try something similar as the MS compiler does. Allocate a little bit more memory then requested and put some marker bytes at the begin and end. When deallocating overwrite the memory with a known pattern. this might help to check if you are still using that memory. for a corrupted stack, you can only try to pin it down by putting log files and finding a scenario that repeatedl reproduces the crash.

Answer (score 1):

fault addr 00000004  =>  means stack was corrupted(very close to 0 addr).

This is an example how you can easily replicate this error be accidentally dereferencing a string like this:

```
int a = foo();
LOGE("Foo() is %d", a ? "ok" : "not ok");
```

it should be "%s" and not "%d"

Hope it helps to someone.

Comment: Why you've decided that it is stack corrupted? More likely it is class data member access by null pointer to class instance.